# Software or tool for employee resource management

Tags: resource-management

Can anybody recommend a tool for managing availability and time scheduling of employees. Peak hours (greatest load), off-peak (average load) and slack (least load) hours are known each day, scheduling should be hence possible on a 1-hour basis for each week day (8:00-9:00, 9:00-10:00, ...) - it'll be nice to be able to insert the number of employees needed for every hour.
Additional advantages would be:
1) a possibility to implement restrictions on a single-employee basis, for example excluding somebody who's worked late shift the previous day from working earliest shift the next day;
2) planing short pause periods during the working shift;
3) possibility to insert the employee vacations, so that the planing for a week excludes those that are not available

It's generally about a simple initial and quick solution, able to run on Windows, preferably free of charge. Not necessary web-based - currently only one person manages the employees availability, so desktop is fine too.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated !
Thanks in advance

Comment: Windows? Linux? Android? Browser? Free, or do you have a budget? The more information that you give us, the more that we can help you. Welcome aboard, but please do read [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in the meantime a free software, that looks visually pretty appealing, and in addition has many of the functionalities desired by me. It's called [ABC Roster](http://www.abc-roster.com/). It is free, but donations accepted.

There is also a well explained documentation PDF file and even a wizard helping you set up a schedule when you first start the program. It is shift-based, you are able to set more than one shift per day, either for different time periods or for different employee functionalities. Employee availability can be set either in terms of time availability or skills. Leaves can be added.

When finished with the scheduling, there is an option to send an e-mail to all employees involved in order to have them informed. Many additional options available - automatic planer, restriction, and so on explained understandable in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

[**Namely**](https://www.namely.com/)

Namely is a web-based platform specializing in core HR and talent management for growing companies. Their product covers payroll and benefits administration, time tracking, performance reviews, and of course, serves as a system of record for all of your employee data. Namely also offers a built in social news feed and custom reports for individual and team metrics.

The system is designed to be adaptable and user-friendly, which makes it stand out against more complicated enterprise solutions. But Namely’s penchant for small and growing companies doesn’t mean they skimp on resources: business clients receive 24/7 customer service through a dedicated Namely account manager. Namely has been used by thousands of small businesses across the globe, as well as some larger brands like Kayak, Mashable, and Vimeo. Full disclosure: TechnologyAdvice currently uses namely for our HR needs.

[**JazzHR**](https://www.jazzhr.com/)

Unlike PeopleMatter and Namely, JazzHR is a best-of-breed HR solution, meaning it’s designed for specialized use—in this case, applicant tracking and interview management. JazzHR helps companies post jobs, screen applications, and manage the interview process through a centralized, real-time platform. Managers can create custom recruiting stages with automated to-dos (e.g. follow-up emails, reminders), and add stakeholders to the process as users with varying permissions and privacy levels.

Post directly to job search sites like indeed, glassdoor, and careerbuilder, and use built-in SEO tools to make sure you’ve chosen the right title and job description. JazzHR also offers social recruiting, employee referral programs, applicant screening, background checks, resume review, branded career sites, interview guides, recruitment calendars, and more.

Comment: Hello, Bilal, thanks for your reply. I found in the meantime a free software, that looks visually pretty appealing, and in addition has many of the functionalities desired by me. It's called ABC Roster and can be accessed at the following link (in case somebody else needs a software with requirements similar to mines posted above): http://www.abc-roster.com/ . There is also a well explained documentation PDF file and even a wizard helping you when you first use the program.